# Latex2html5 Javascript issue : fill parallelogram

Tags: javascript, latex, pstricks

Using [latex2html5 Javascript library](http://latex2html5.com/), I try to fill a parallelogram with grey color and solid fillstyle.

This library has a subset of `pstricks` latex functions, so my issue may not be solved.

Here's [the link of my current version][2]. My issue is that, once page is loaded and parallelogram is drawn and filled (see grey area), if I move the mouse over or near the figure, **the black diagonal segment of the middle disappears automatically** and I don't know to prevent this.

The specific part to fill the parallelogram is :

```
% Fill 
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1pt, linecolor=grey, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=grey]{-2}{0}{-2-0.25*x}
\psplot[algebraic,linewidth=1pt, linecolor=grey, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=grey]{-2}{0}{2-0.25*x}
```

I didn't find how to fix this behavior, if someone could see what's wrong ...

**UPDATE 1:**

the concerned diagonal segment disappears only when I move the mouse horizontally and remains displayed if I move vertically the mouse. You can check it on [the above link][2]

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to a Latex2Html glitch. Script refreshes the SVG output on hover event and parallelogram is appended at the end of the SVG, so it overlaps the grid. If your grid is placed before the psplot in your TeX document, try to put it to the end:

```
\begin{pspicture}
  \psplot ...
  \psplot ...
  \psaxes ...
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: thanks, actually, I solved my issue by using \pspolygon.